# How to do animation in iphone/ipad application

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, animation

I want to rotate one disk in my iphone/ipad application.And on that rotate I want select particular area from that disk like in pie chart application.If any one know that then please tell me.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: What have you done so far, what's working, what isn't, what does the code structure look like... etc..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read [Apple's CoreAnimation Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), [the Quartz 2D programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066) or, if you want to accomplish something more "sophisticated", learn OpenGL ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, placardView is basically UIView

```
CALayer *pLayer = placardView.layer;

float radians = 3.120;

CATransform3D transforms;
transforms = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

CABasicAnimation *aAnimation;
aAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

aAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
aAnimation.duration = spinSpeed;
aAnimation.cumulative = YES;
aAnimation.repeatCount = 1e100f;  // this is infinity in IEEE 754 floating point format

[pLayer addAnimation:aAnimation forKey:@"animatePlacardViewToSpin"];
```

Comment: If you wanna make it to rotate opposite way, just use transforms = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);